# Simple RewriteRule

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I'm trying to write a RewriteRule to make a simple url. I want users to be able to type enter

```
www.example.com/somepage
```

and have it take them to

```
www.example.com/abc/somepage.php
```

How can this be done in .htaccess?

I've tried these to no avail:

```
RewriteRule ^somepage$ abc/somepage.php [L]

RewriteRule ^/somepage$ /abc/somepage.php [L]
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: As it turns out, this isn't a simple duplicate of the "Apache htaccess redirects" question, linked to above, since the answer is dependent on the nginx server.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is in the .htaccess in your document root, then you are almost there. You just seem to be missing the `/` (slash - directory separator) from the front of your destination URL (in the first example).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^somepage$ /abc/somepage.php [R=301,L]
```

The slash (or whatever is the base URL) is automatically removed from the request URI when pattern matching, which is why it is not present in the pattern (`^somepage$`).

This will perform an *external redirect* (`R=301`) - so the destination URL will show in the browser. Remove the `R` flag to perform an *internal rewrite* (URL won't change).

Comment: Thanks for the response. This isn't working for me.. I have no idea why. And sorry, I meant to only have `[L]`, so the dest url will not show in the user's browser.

Comment: This is the literal code: `RewriteRule ^hatfinder$ /gbi/hatfinder.php [L]` You can see it not working here: `www.goorin.com/hatfinder`

Comment: In what way "not working"? Does anything happen? Is mod_rewrite enabled? Is `FollowSymLinks` enabled?

Comment: Yes, they are both enabled. I'm getting 404

Comment: Do you have any other directives in your htaccess file that could be messing things up?

Comment: I don't think so. I had tried putting the code above the other rewrites, just in case, and got the same results.

Comment: Maybe there is some kind of test we can do, like rewrite some foobar url to google.com or something.

Comment: Is a rewrite-loop occuring, resulting in the URL being rewritten again? What happens if you redirect (`R=301`) instead? Does it redirect to the correct URL?

Comment: It does not. Wish I could be more helpful.. I know it's something stupid on my part.

Comment: I'm using the Magneto framework with nginx. I'm wondering if it something in the nginx config that isn't allowing this.. I'll have to look into that.

Comment: Dang, I didn't pick up on your `nginx` tag earlier! htaccess and mod_rewrite are Apache, isn't the URL rewriting engine on nginx different (`rewrite` instead of `RewriteRule` etc.) - sorry, I'm not familiar. If the above redirect is not working then it would seem that the directive is not being interpreted. (Your page seems to be doing some kind of non-HTTP redirect at the moment?!)

Comment: Oh man lol. The rewriting should be very similar to Apache, it is RewriteRule. I'm using a Magento CMS page to redirect using javascript for the time being ><

Comment: So I figured it out.. the rewrites are handled in the .conf files for the nginx server. They can be done in .htaccess, but the .conf doesn't let it get that far it seems.. (not sure why we still have a .htaccess file), and you're right, in the .conf file it is written `rewrite`